# Pontuar usuário que acessou o site 4 dias seguidos

Tags: php, sql, banco-de-dados, mysqli, tabela-banco-de-dados

Toda vez que o usuário entra no sistema (efetua login), seus dados são salvos no banco de dados, incluindo uma coluna Timestamp.

Estou perdido para resolver o seguinte problema:

```
if (usuario entrou 4 dias SEGUIDOS) 
{echo " Ganha 10";}
else { echo " Não ganha nada "; }
```

Sinceramente não consegui pensar em uma escrita de poucos códigos, 
tudo que me vem a mente são dezenas de linhas (gambiarras).

Será que existe uma forma simples de resolver ?

Agradecido !

Comment: Poste seu código para podermos ajudar

Answer (score 0):

O que fiz foi o seguinte:

Quando o usuário entra realizo uma consulta:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ed_sv_dadosnavegador where idaluno = '$id' and data = '$data_anterior' ";
```

Criei uma condicional, se o $sql acima retorna algo maior que 0, quer dizer que existe uma data no banco que corresponde com o dia anterior então adiciona-se +1 na coluna "conta_acesso"

```
$result  = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result ->num_rows > 0) {    

  $set = 'conta_acesso = conta_acesso + 1, data = 0 ';  }
```

Se é falso, eu zero a contagem

```
else { $set = 'conta_acesso = 0 ';  };
```

Esse código abaixo é o update em execução

```
$sqlup = "UPDATE `ed_sv_dadosnavegador` SET $set WHERE `idaluno` = '$id' ORDER BY conta_aceso, id LIMIT 1 ";
if ($conn->query($sqlup) === TRUE) {
$mensagemalerta = "Tudo certo";}
```

Por mais bagunçado que tudo isso possa parecer esta funcionando. O ÚNICO problema que me deparei agora é que ao colocar LIMIT 1 na $sqlup, em caso de verdadeiro, eu não consigo limpar a data das tabelas e se eu não fizer isso, quando o usuário atualiza a página inicia uma nova contagem.

Sou iniciante, desculpe a bagunça, mas fiquei a noite toda só nisso, se alguém puder dar uma ajuda, melhorada, toda sugestão é bem vinda !

Comment: Resolvi fazendo dois update diferentes, seguindo a mesma lógica, funciona bem !